# Prove Per(A)=1 if and only if A is a permutation matrix

Tags: matrices, permutations, latin-square, permanent

Assume A is a doubly stochastic matrix. I was only able to show if A is a permutation matrix, then per(A)=1. I wonder how to prove conversely? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Note that there is a trivial bound $\textrm{per}(A)\leq\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n}\left(\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}a_{kj}\right)$ (for matrices $A$ with nonnegative entries). Hence, for doubly stochastic matrix $A$ we have $\textrm{per}(A)\leq 1$. Then, you need to find out when does the equality occur.

Comment: could you provide more details?

Comment: Expand the right hand side and note that all terms of permanent are also appear in the right hand side. Hence, the equality occurs when all remaining terms are equal to 0.